# Getting the first element of a comma delimited field during a foreach loop (SQL Razor)

Tags: sql, asp.net, razor, foreach

How do I extract the first image name from a comma delimited field `location_images` in my `SQL` database during a `foreach` loop.

`FirstorDefault()` doesn't seem to work.

```
@foreach (var row in selectedPlace)
{
  var selectedImages = row.location_images;
}

<img src="https://test.com/img/@selectedImages" />
```

Comment: `string.Split(',')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

So, the images are Comma delimited, then you can simply split it on the basis of comma and get the first `string` from the returned array of strings.

```
var firstImage = row.location_images.Split(',').First();
```

Comment: Sorry @jamshaid-kamran I'm still getting errors.  "" Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'  "

Comment: @Mark Please use `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` then check. I've edited my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working with 2 changes:

1. Search String was modified: to exclude records without any images,
   and
2. Using: var firstImage = row.location_images.Split(',')[0];

It's still not ideal, as I can't see which records have missing images, but will do for now.

Thanks guys!